# regex find throwing StackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex

I am using below pattern to find groups in my content.  This is to parse multipart request body data

```
private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[\r\n]*Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"([^\"]*)\"[\r\n]+((.*[\r\n])*)------$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
if (matcher.find()) {
...
}
```

This is working for normal content(let say number of line 1000), but same thing is not working for large content(lets say 10000 line of content). Below is the error i am getting HTTP 500

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match0(Pattern.java:3760)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$Curly.match(Pattern.java:3744)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupHead.match(Pattern.java:4168)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$Loop.match(Pattern.java:4295)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupTail.match(Pattern.java:4227)
    java.util.regex.Pattern$BmpCharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3366)
```

Thanks for the help,
Madhu-

Comment: It could be due to the `(.*[\r\n])*` part (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS). Try to replace by `.*` while enabling the DOTALL flag: `Pattern.compile("...", Pattern.DOTALL)` (or hack this behavior with `[\s\S]+` for example).

Comment: Could you try replacing `(.*[\r\n])*` with `([^\r\n]*[\r\n])*`